# Python3 create a UTC date from string

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, utc

I have an API response which returns a date time object in String. I need to convert it into a UTC Datetime object to compare with the current datetime.

How do I convert this to an UTC DateTime object?

```
received    "2019-03-22T06:35:57Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string and convert to datetime using strptime.

```
import datetime
dateob =  datetime.datetime.strptime ("2019-03-22T06:35:57Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

To convert to UTC:

```
>>> def Local2UTC(LocalTime):
...     EpochSecond = time.mktime(LocalTime.timetuple())
...     utcTime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(EpochSecond)
...     return utcTime
```

Comment: will this give me a UTC DateTime ?

Comment: Use `def Local2UTC(LocalTime):` method to convert to UTC time.